# CakePHP 1.3 Blank White page on VPS but not on shared Cpanel

Tags: cakephp-1.3

So I have a CakePHP 1.3 project set up a long time ago and when I put it into the shared cpanel webhost that I bought on some site, it shows the admin login page. But when I put it on my vps it shows up as a blank white screen with the title. I tried the sample cakephp 1.3 app on the vps and it worked, just not my old project.
[Blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl9xs.png)

Phpinfo from Cpanel: http://robloxgifts.win/test/test.php
Phpinfo from VPS: http://91.209.70.77

Comment: If you could add some code to your post, and the phpinfo() of the VPS, that would be helpful.

Comment: Code is too complicated. It's a project that I worked on for months 5 years ago. Has too many things almost 20k line post controller.

Comment: How would I post the phpinfo()?

Comment: put this in a php file on your server, load the page in your browser, then copy/paste:
<? phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: not showing any code at all though is not going to help solve your problems.  If we can't see the code to know what's wrong, we can't diagnose.  do you have access to your old cpanel site?  If so, having the phpinfo from that site to compare with will help.

Comment: I can get the phpinfo, its just how do I post it on here, the whole thing

Comment: There I posted it

Comment: I can see the one from the VPS but the other comes up with a DNS error

Comment: ok so what I can see so far, you have some differences in the php configurations between the two. that should not affect Cake, but it may affect your app.  what you should do is check the requirements for php for your app and make sure they are all met. Also, check your apache error logs. they should tell you something as well.  Since your VPS is running PHP as an apache module instead of as cgi, you should check permissions of your scripts as well.